# Can components be aligned with each other, belonging to different views?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, kotlin

I am building a view (.xml) that is made up, in turn, by components of other views (different.xml).

Is there a way to align one icon with another, even if they belong to different views?

That is, in a fragment the upper part is loaded from an .xml with an icon and the lower part from another .xml with another icon. Both also have other components. I want to align the mentioned icons from one .xml and the other to each other.

In the image that I attached would be, for example, the share icon and the heart icon.

As a requirement, I can't modify the components (for example, use "include", or copy one and paste it into the other view).

```
Thanks in advance :)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Constraintslayout Percentage Bias Like: "layout_constraintHorizontal_bias:"0.4" or Guidelines in both views and handle with same percentages

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
              android:id="@+id/guidelineVertialLeft"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              app:layout_constraintGuide_percent=".04" />
```